# PHP forward_static_call vs call_user_func

Tags: php, php-5.3

What is the difference between `forward_static_call` and `call_user_func`

And the same question applies to `forward_static_call_array` and `call_user_func_array`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is just that `forward_static_call` does not reset the "called class" information if going up the class hierarchy and explicitly naming a class, whereas `call_user_func` resets the information in those circumstances (but still does not reset it if using `parent`, `static` or `self`).

Example:

```
<?php
class A {
    static function bar() { echo get_called_class(), "\n"; }
}
class B extends A {
    static function foo() {
        parent::bar(); //forwards static info, 'B'
        call_user_func('parent::bar'); //forwarding, 'B'
        call_user_func('static::bar'); //forwarding, 'B'
        call_user_func('A::bar'); //non-forwarding, 'A'
        forward_static_call('parent::bar'); //forwarding, 'B'
        forward_static_call('A::bar'); //forwarding, 'B'
    }
}
B::foo();
```

Note that `forward_static_call` refuses to forward if going *down* the class hierarchy:

```
<?php
class A {
    static function foo() {
        forward_static_call('B::bar'); //non-forwarding, 'B'
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static function bar() { echo get_called_class(), "\n"; }
}
A::foo();
```

Finally, note that `forward_static_call` can only be called from within a class method.

Comment: +1 from the horse's mouth. *`I've been a PHP developer since late 2010`*.

Comment: There's another thing worth mentioning, if the method `B::foo()` isn't static, then all calls to `A::bar()` will output `B`. Try it. Instantiate an object `$b = new B()` and call `$b->foo()`. Then make the method non-static and run the program again.