# Is there differences between call_user_func() and $var()?

Tags: php

Is there any differences between `call_user_func()` and its syntactic sugar version...

```
// Global function

$a = 'max';

echo call_user_func($a, 1, 2); // 2
echo $a(1, 2); // 2

// Class method

class A {

   public function b() {
     return __CLASS__;
   }

   static function c() {
      return 'I am static!';
   }

}

$a = new A;
$b = 'b';

echo call_user_func(array($a, $b)); // A
echo $a->$b(); // A

// Static class method

$c = 'c';

echo call_user_func(array('A', $c)); // I am static!
echo a::$c(); // I am static!
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/QHdhkgKu).

Both output the same, but I was [recently hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061476/php-forward-static-call-vs-call-user-func/5061495#5061495) (10k+ rep only) that they are *not* equivalent.

So, what, if any, are the differences?

Comment: Pfft, "10k+ rep only". Quit bragging ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First difference I can think of is that `call_user_func()` runs `method` as a callback.

This means you can use a closure, eg

```
echo call_user_func(function($a, $b) {
    return max($a, $b);
}, 1, 2);
```

This would be more of an implementation difference versus a usage or performance (execution) one though.

Answer (score 6):

I honestly can't find much of a difference between the two.  They basically do the same thing, but the only differences I can find is that `call_user_func` takes over 2× longer to complete than variable functions (calling an empty function).

Another thing is that the error handlers are different, if you use a non-existent callback function, the variable function would output a fatal error and halt the script while `call_user_func` would output a warning but continue the script.

Also when passing parameters through the function, using variable functions provides a little more detail in the error in relation to line numbers:

```
function asdf($a, $b) {
  return(1);
}
```

> **call_user_func('asdf', 1)**:
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for asdf()
>   in G:\test.php on line 3

-

> **$a='asdf'; $a($a, 1)**:
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   asdf(), called in G:\test.php on line
>   10 and defined in G:\test.php on line 3

These errors are collected from Command-Line Interface (CLI) tests, the display of errors obviously depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is that you can pass by reference using variable functions:

```
<?php

function a(&$b) {}
$c = "ABC";

call_user_func('a', $c);
```

Gives a warning "PHP Warning:  a(): Argument #1 ($b) must be passed by reference, value given in /tmp/main.php on line 6"

Whereas

```
<?php

function a(&$b) {}
$c = "ABC";
$d = "a";

$d($c);
```

Does not give any warnings.

Another way to pass by reference is using `call_user_func_array` as noted in the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).